# PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM. Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell, ssd, format

I have a Dell inspiron n 5110. The laptop was working fine with ubuntu 14.04 desktop.
I recently changed my hard drive to an ssd patriot 2.5'' SATA III 6Gps. 
I have downloaded an installation file  ubuntu 16.04 desktop 64bit and stored on USB memory. 
I constantly get the same message :

```
PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM.

Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_
```

Any ideas on how to move on and complete my installation?

Comment: You have to make the USB bootable first. And make sure the mode of the USB and your boot mode in BIOS is matching. For eg. if your boot mode in BIOS is legacy, the bootable USB should also be in legacy (MBR) mode. MBR is a bit obsolete, UEFI is widely used now. Use Rufus (Windows only) to create the bootable USB. You can also use Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu itself.

Comment: What is the boot order in BIOS?

Comment: Can I work this on chrome OS environment? I have ni device on working Windows. So do I need to place my old HDD in order to complete that? Thanks for your answer Kulfy

Comment: @IoannisTs No you need not to place old HDD back. Hit F12 or F2 as soon as Dell logo appears to get into BIOS settings. Check the boot options there. Also, what do you mean by Chrome OS environment?

Comment: Chrome OS is the operating system of chromebook. I wonder if I can work this bios on my chromebook. One more thing my usb stick is 4giga. Do I just copy paste the iso file there?

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu on ChromeBook or Dell Inspiron system?

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu on Dell but I am using Chromebook for support I am still getting the screen:  "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot  Media in selected Boot device and press a key". I did try to format my 4gig USB on my Chromebook and then add my iso file but the dell system still not recognise the USB installation file. I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.06 or 16.06 LTS version on 64bit.  I am thinking of putting back on my old HD and complete USB format on that? Any ideas/help or step by step simple detailed guide installation?

Comment: yes it does thanx a lot Kulfy